# bootmgr image is corrupted...the system cannot boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I just wanted to learn linux and use it beside my windows 7...so I watched a dual-boot video on youtube and do all the instructions:
1-shrink hard disk volume on windows (this new space is for ubuntu)
2-using this new disk as following:
  500 mb for a swap area
  the rest space as primary and as root
3-install ubuntu.
the process went smoothly and when I restart the pc I see the GRUB menu and I can choose ubuntu and boot successfully but when I choose Windows 7 the following message appear:
"bootmgr image is corrupted...the system cannot boot"
and I can't boot into windows 7 .
What should I do to be able to boot in windows 7 again??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you defragmented your windows 7 partition before installing ubuntu ? You should doing that before
doing modifications into this partition (exemple: resize it to install ubuntu).

It's an important error and i can't find a proper solution.

You can boot into your ubuntu livecd and install the package boot-repair.
Documentation here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Did you have the windows 7 DVD? If so follow this link: https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/ Have you made a backup of your files before installing Ubuntu ?

Comment: I haven't defragmented any partitions before installing ubuntu...I have a windows dvd ...Also I have a backup of my pc but It is an old backup(four years ago maybe)

Comment: 1. Insert the Windows 7 installation disc and restart your computer.
    2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next".
    3. Click "Repair your computer".